# How to apply or assign custom view mode to user display?

Tags: users, display-suite, entities

I am using [Display Suites](https://www.drupal.org/project/ds). I have created a custom view mode and have made it available to the user display per Display Suite documentation, but I cannot figure out how to apply the custom view mode to the user display.  It always shows in the default view mode.

If I were editing a node, there would be a vertical tab called Display Settings that would have a field for selecting the view mode to use.  When editing an existing user profile, there is no Display Settings tab.

---

In various Drupal issues queues, specifically [Display Suites](https://www.drupal.org/project/ds), [Panels](https://www.drupal.org/project/panels) and [Profile 2](https://www.drupal.org/project/profile2), other users have asked essentially this same question: How do I assign a custom view mode to the user profile display?

Is the Drupal core responsible for user data and display?  Perhaps the problem lies there instead of with whatever module.

Comment: Maybe edit [user-profile.tpl.php](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user-profile.tpl.php/7) to include your view?

Comment: Thanks @Daniel Rogers.  My issue is that I want to use different view modes to display the user profile differently in different places.  I can add the view to the tpl.php, but I still can't use view modes on the user profile the way they are meant to be used.

Answer (score 1):

The question is too old, but for those who are still looking similar functionality. We can implement [hook_entity_view_mode_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_entity_view_mode_alter/7.x) in our custom module and change the rendered view mode dynamically. Check sample below:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_entity_view_mode_alter().
 */
function MODULE_NAME_entity_view_mode_alter(&$view_mode, $context) {
  // For nodes, change the view mode when in full display mode.
  // Add/Remove any condition based on requirement.
  if ($context['entity_type'] == 'node' && $view_mode == 'full') {
    $view_mode = 'teaser';
  }
}
```